# CanUserResize=false for DataGridRowHeader

Tags: wpf, datagrid, resize

You can disable resizing the columns of a datagrid.

Is there a way to stop resizing the rowsheader Height

At this moment the user can resize the row Headers. Like this:

[image: Guten Tag]

I want to disable this. So it should always look:

[image]

That's my RowHeaderTemplate

```
         <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel FlowDirection="LeftToRight" DataContext="{Binding Item,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ZimmerNummer}" MinWidth="48" MaxWidth="48" />
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
```

That was my idea:

```
<DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
        <Setter Property="MaxHeight"
            Value="55"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
```

But it was not work. That was the result:

[image]

Do someone know a Solution for that?

Comment: Do you want to disable row/column resizing by user?

Comment: yes that is what i want

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to disable resizing on your `DataGrid` then you can do something like this:

```
<DataGrid CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" .../>
```

Comment: I don't suppose there's any shortcut to setting all `CanUserXXX` properties to false?